# Clickable td in IE

Tags: html

I have issue with cursor pointer on TD in IE 6++.
There is a table cell with such HTML code, the click event `BlockDay` works only on second div, but i wrote it on all TD.

```
    <TD class="calnedar_td" onclick="BlockDay('1340571600');return false;">
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left"></DIV>
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: right">Mon 25</DIV>
    </TD>

   .calnedar_td{
     height:105px;
     width:105px;
     vertical-align: top;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 3px;
     cursor:pointer;
    }
```

How can i made all td area clickable?
Thank you, Anton.

Comment: Clicking the blank area in IE8 works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/Bpya8/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
// place this in your ready event

$('td.calnedar_td').bind("click", function(){
           // whatever
});
```

Comment: each calendar td have own `BlockDay('1340571600')` onclick function parametr

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you will have to put something inside the second DIV for you to click on..! I may be wrong, but the event handler may require something to actually be clickable before it can use the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to place something inside of each TD that you with to make clickable this way. If the cell is not meant to have anything it, just add a non-breaking space as below:

```
<TD class="calnedar_td" onclick="BlockDay('1340571600');return false;">
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left">&nbsp;</DIV>
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: right">Mon 25</DIV>
    </TD>
```